# Join two strings from db together

Tags: mysql

I have produced the following query.

```
SELECT       t.id AS playerid,
             dp.first_name,
             dp.surname
FROM         ".TBL_FOOT_CAREER_TEAMS." t 
  INNER JOIN ".TBL_FOOT_CAREER_DB_PLAYERS." dp
  ON         dp.id = t.playerid
WHERE        t.careerid = '$career'
  AND       (dp.first_name LIKE '%{$keyword[$i]}%')
  OR        (dp.surname LIKE '%{$keyword[$i]}%')
  OR        (`dp.first_name + dp.surname` LIKE '%{$keyword[$i]}%')
```

There are two columns in the database. `first_name` and `surname`. As you can see, I'm trying to check if the keyword is in either of those columns. I also try and make them into one complete name and check if that's what the search term is aswell.

I'm getting an error so I can assume this isn't the way to do it!!

Can someone help :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id AS playerid, 
       dp.first_name, 
       dp.surname 
FROM ".TBL_FOOT_CAREER_TEAMS." t 
            INNER JOIN ".TBL_FOOT_CAREER_DB_PLAYERS." dp 
            ON dp.id = t.playerid
WHERE (t.careerid = '$career') AND  
      (
         (dp.first_name LIKE concat('%', $keyword[$i], '%')) OR 
         (dp.surname LIKE concat('%', $keyword[$i], '%')) OR 
         (CONCAT(dp.first_name, ' ',dp.surname) LIKE concat('%', $keyword[$i], '%'))
      )
```

**UPDATE**

since you are concactenating the name, you can it like this:

```
SELECT t.id AS playerid, 
       dp.first_name, 
       dp.surname 
FROM ".TBL_FOOT_CAREER_TEAMS." t 
            INNER JOIN ".TBL_FOOT_CAREER_DB_PLAYERS." dp 
            ON dp.id = t.playerid
WHERE (t.careerid = '$career') AND  
      ( 
         CONCAT(dp.first_name, ' ',dp.surname) LIKE concat('%', $keyword[$i], '%')
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT()` in your query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 0):

```
...
OR CONCAT(dp.first_name, dp.surname) LIKE '%{$keyword[$i]}%'
```